# Right approach to a full text search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a search function that has to search through some tables. I first added a FULL TEXT index on all fields that need to be searched (so 1 index on multiple fields).

Then, in my PHP, I do the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST('search word')
```

Is this the correct approach? Or should I add the indexes on each field separately, also separating the query (`MATCH (field1) AGAINST ... OR MATCH (field2) AGAINST...`).

What would be the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the FULL TEXT index + MATCH method is valid and shouldn't have any issues. Just make sure that your 3 fields are either CHAR, TEXT or VARCHAR.

Maybe you would be interested in also retrieving the "score" of the MATCH. It can be done like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST('search word') as score FROM table WHERE MATCH (field1, field2, field3) AGAINST('search word') ORDER BY score
```

This "score" will tell you how good was each of the matches found.

Maybe you should also take a look at `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. You have to put it right after the AGAINST particle (`AGAINST('search word') IN BOOLEAN MODE`), it will take into consideration operators in the search, similar to a google search.

For example:

+table: the word 'table' must appear in all the matches.

~table: the word 'table' must not appear in any match.